# How the Play Store apps update really work?

Tags: android

i was searching a lot of information about this, and may seem is a duplicated topic, but.. i have a specific question:

My app have a database, of course with user information... when the Play Store update the app in the users phone, how this work? they uninstall the old app?, the database in the old app is delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the database will stay. Unless you want to change the database in which case you have to change the version number of your database in your program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQLiteOpenHelper you must implement this method:

```
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
```

It will be executed in the update process.
The versioning of the database must be managed by yourself based on the oldVersion and newVersion.

If the app is unnistalled by the user the database will be lost.